# Converting JSON to HTML Table

Tags: php

What is the best way for me to convert a json file to a html output

I have a script that outputs some json. My json looks like:

```
[ { "description" : "desc 1 test",
    "image" : "Http://test.com/gram.png",
    "money" : null,
    "title" : "title2"
  },
  { "description" : "desc 2 test",
    "image" : "http://test.com/daddy.gif",
    "money" : "$7",
    "title" : "title2"
  },
  { "description" : "desc 3 test",
    "image" : "test.com/41057.png",
    "money" : null,
    "title" : "title3"
  }
]
```

I want it to spit something out like this below (test data), but notice the classes are odd and even - I don't know how I would go about that.

```
<tr class="gradeA">
            <td>title1</td>
            <td class="center">image1</td>
            <td class="center">desc1</td>
            <td class="center">money1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>title2</td>
            <td class="center">image2</td>
            <td class="center">desc2</td>
            <td class="center">money2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>title3</td>
            <td class="center">image3</td>
            <td class="center">desc3</td>
            <td class="center">money3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>title4</td>
            <td class="center">image4</td>
            <td class="center">desc4</td>
            <td class="center">money4</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: But the classes you provided in your example aren't odd and even?

Comment: You can use `$res=json_decode($json);` for decode it to a php array

Comment: It's called `zebra striping`, do a quick search for that term (maybe append `CSS` to the search term) and you'll find more than you need.

Comment: You can use CSS pseudo-selectors `.gradeA:odd` and `.gradeA:even` instead of doing it in your PHP.

Comment: Thanks, actually I didn't know the name 'Zebra Striping'! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
$str = "json code";
$arr = @json_decode($str)[0]; 
$html = "<table>";

$even = true;

forach ( $arr as $value ) {

    $html .= "<tr class = '" . ( $even ? 'even' : 'odd' ) . "'>";
    $html .= "<td>{$value['title']}</td>";
    $html .= "<td>{$value['image']}</td>";
    $html .= "<td>{$value['description']}</td>";
    $html .= "<td>{$value['money']}</td>";
    $html .= "</tr>";

    $even = !$even; 

}
$html .= "</table>";
```

Comment: usually php wont be happy about accessing method as array json_decode($str)[0]; you can do it in two lines without the @ character, but it will be the same

Comment: just like that $arr = json_decode($str);


$arr = isset($arr[0]) ? $arr[0] : array();

Comment: either your json is bad or remove the [0] at second line. try print_r($arr); to see what you got

Comment: that could have also been first line after foreach, try new one